# How to pass a String data from a complex data type stored in a list view to another activity in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass some data from from one activity to another through intents. The data I intend to pass is stored in a list view. The data is of a custom type, for which I have mode a POJO class. It consists of a String and an icon. What I need to do is to pass just the string Title to the next activity. I am a beginner to android and dont have much XP on this. Please help me.

Here is the code for the activity from which I want to pass data:

```
public class CuisinesFragment extends Fragment{
    ArrayList<CuisinesListItem> cuisinesListItems=new ArrayList<CuisinesListItem>();
    public CuisinesFragment(){

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cuisines,container,false);
        ListView lv=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.all_cuisines_list);
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("American",R.mipmap.a1));
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("British",R.mipmap.b1));
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("Caribbean",R.mipmap.c1));
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("Chinese",R.mipmap.c2));
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("French",R.mipmap.f1));
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("Greek",R.mipmap.g1));
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("Indian",R.mipmap.i1));
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("Italian",R.mipmap.i2));
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("Japanese",R.mipmap.j1));
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("Mediterranean",R.mipmap.m1));
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("Mexican",R.mipmap.m2));
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("Moroccan",R.mipmap.m3));
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("Spanish",R.mipmap.s1));
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("Thai",R.mipmap.t1));
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("Turkish",R.mipmap.t2));
        cuisinesListItems.add(new CuisinesListItem("Vietnamese",R.mipmap.v1));

        CuisinesListAdapter adapter=new CuisinesListAdapter(rootView.getContext(),cuisinesListItems);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                //Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(),"You tapped on this item : "+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(rootView.getContext(),CuisineDishes.class);
                intent.putExtra("CuisineName",);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I want to pass String like "America", or "British" from the ArrayList as shown.
cuisineListItems is of type CuisineListItem which is a POJO class and has a STring title and int Icon inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
intent.putExtra("CuisineName",cuisinesListItems.get(position).getTitle());
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do that in the onItemClick() method? You have position in the method, so you can get the object at that position, then get the string from that object and pass it in the intent's method putExtra.

Answer (score 0):

change your  `intent.putExtra("CuisineName",);`
to

```
intent.putExtra("StringKey", cuisinesListItems.get(position).getCuisineName().toString());
intent.putExtra("IntegerKey", cuisinesListItems.get(position).getCuisineImageId());
```

and on Receiver Side:

```
 Intent mIntent = getIntent();
 String cuisineName = mIntent.getStringExtra("Stringkey");
 int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("IntegerKey", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

With use of 'raw types' you can do that, but that is not good practice. Because if you didn't handle well it produce ClassCastException at run time.

Answer (score 0):

In your OnItemClickListener you can get the clicked CuisinesListItem

```
CuisineListItem item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

Then get your title from item and add it to the intent.putExtra